# Apache Pig - Create unique output folder using UDF

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig, hue

I am using Apache Pig from  Hue to perform ETL operations on files using the script **etl-op.pig**. The output is stored into the specified folder in HDFS using the following line:

```
STORE outval INTO '/user/root/Pig-Output
```

However next time when the script is run, it says the output folder already exists and doesn't create a separate folder.

Is there any way to create a Java UDF in Pig using Hue so that a unique identifier can be generated and appended to the 'Pig-Output' folder name present in the script ?

Comment: What type of identified do you need? A popular way is to just add a variable, e.g. ''STORE outval INTO '/user/root/Pig-Output/$output"

Comment: @Romain: What value will $output contain ?

Comment: You will be prompted to provide the value at submission.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without UDF: 
Define a variable like the current unix timestamp:

```
%default TS `date  +%s`
```

And than use it as e.g. a postfix of your folder:

```
STORE outval INTO '/user/root/Pig-Output_$TS' ...
```